# Convert XML Message file to CSV

Tags: c#, xml, csv

I'm receiving the following XML message from an ATM processing deposits. Now it should be converted to CSV and saved. Since it is not a simply structured XML, I have some problems with it. I can't display the data individually in CSV.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RemoteMessage operation="Device OK" DeviceID="SDM100-02378" CustomerCode="12345" Date="2020-09-06" Time="14:30:10" NOP="3013">
<content>
<count machineId="4" den="0.05" curr="CHF" qty="9" type="C" N="0" sType="B"/>
</content>
<devStatus>
<dev name="BDM" machineId="3" mod="SDM 100S" err="KO" devS="2"/>
<dev name="CDM" machineId="4" mod="CDS 508 (BV DE0)" err="OK" clean="0" door="0" devS="1" bag="2" cov="0" blk="00000000" ext="0"/>
</devStatus>
</RemoteMessage>
```

Here's what I tried:

```
txtXML.Text = File.ReadAllText(comboBoxPath.Text);

var input = txtXML.Text;

// 1) Replace closing and opening tags with commas.
//    Include quotes in case any values have commas in them.
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\S)<\/[^>]*>\s*<[^>]*>(\S)", "$1\",\"$2");

// 2) Put in CSV line breaks and remove xml delimiters, include leading and trailing quotes
result = Regex.Replace(result, @"<\/[^>]*>\s*<\/RemoteMessage>\s*<RemoteMessage>\s*<[^>]*>", "\r\n");

// 3) Remove remaining tags and trim any whitespace
result = Regex.Replace(result, @"\s*<.*>\s*", "");

// 4) put in header row and first and last quotes            
result = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd") + ", " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + ", " + "d, " + "content" + result + "";

txtCSV.Text = result;
```

I tried that too:

```
using (CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\CSVMessage.csv"))
using (XmlRecordReader reader = new XmlRecordReader(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\XMLMessage.xml", "RemoteMessage/RemoteMessage"))
{
     reader.Columns.Add("content", "content");
     //reader.Columns.Add("devStatus", "devStatus");                

     writer.Write("machineId");
     //writer.Write("name");

     writer.EndRecord();

     while (reader.ReadRecord())
     {
        writer.Write(reader["machineId"]);
        //writer.Write(reader["name"]);
        
        writer.EndRecord();
     }
     reader.Close();
     writer.Close();
}
```

Both examples only provide the titles, but no values. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication176
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.csv";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(INPUT_FILENAME);
            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(xml);
            XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(sReader);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RemoteMessage));
            RemoteMessage remoteMessage = (RemoteMessage)serializer.Deserialize(xReader);

            string[] headers = new string[] {
                "operation",
                "DeviceID",
                "CustomerCode",
                "Date",
                "NOP",
                "machineId",
                "den",
                "curr",
                "qty",
                "type",
                "N",
                "sType",
                "name",
                "machineID",
                "mod",
                "err",
                "devS"
            };
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(OUTPUT_FILENAME);
            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", headers));

            string remoteMessageStr = string.Join(",",
                remoteMessage.operation,
                remoteMessage.DeviceID,
                remoteMessage.CustomerCode,
                remoteMessage.Date.Add(remoteMessage.GetTime()),
                remoteMessage.NOP
                );

            string content = string.Join(",", 
                remoteMessage.content.First().machineId,
                remoteMessage.content.First().den,
                remoteMessage.content.First().curr,
                remoteMessage.content.First().qty,
                remoteMessage.content.First().type,
                remoteMessage.content.First().N,
                remoteMessage.content.First().sType
                );

            foreach(Device device in remoteMessage.devices)
            {
                string deviceStr = string.Join(",",
                    device.name,
                    device.machineId,
                    device.mod,
                    device.err,
                    device.devS
                    );

                writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", remoteMessageStr, content, deviceStr));
            }


            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();


        }
    }
    public class RemoteMessage
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string operation { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string DeviceID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string CustomerCode { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        
        [XmlAttribute()]
        private TimeSpan _time { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public DateTime Time 
        {
            get { return new DateTime().Add(_time); }
            set { _time = value.TimeOfDay; } 
        }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int  NOP { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("content")]
        [XmlArrayItem("count")]
        public List<Content> content { get; set; }
        [XmlArray("devStatus")]
        [XmlArrayItem("dev")]
        public List<Device> devices { get; set; }

        public TimeSpan GetTime()
        {
            return _time;
        }

    }
    public class Content
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int machineId { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public decimal den { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string curr { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int qty { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string type { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int N { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string sType { get; set; }
    }
    public class Device
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int machineId { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string mod { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string err { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string devS { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, I integrated that into the "Form App" and created the three classes. The document is created, but remains empty. Then the Excel is created with write protection. Any Idea?

Comment: I tested it with a console application and everything works fine. With a form application, however, the created document remains empty. There is no error message. Any Idea?

Comment: There is no difference in running this code in a form or a console.  Put a break point and make sure the code gets executed.  Make sure you are reading the correct xml file.

Comment: I let the read XML appear in a TextBox, so I can be sure that it will be read correctly. The paths are the same for both applications. The code is also absolutely identical. I can't explain why there is an output with the console and not with the form.

Comment: I found the problem. Now everything is going as it should. Many thanks!!